# Applescript: Get path of files copied to the clipboard

Tags: applescript, bash, copy-paste

I like to get the paths of files that I have copied by using CMD+c in Finder programmatically. I.e.,:

```
getPathOfClipboard.applescript

# Should output the paths of the copied files in each line like so:
# /Users/hi/Downloads/Mozilla.Firefox.70.0.1.EN.x64.zip
# /Users/hi/Downloads/jarvis.pmdl
```

I don't care what language I need to use to do this (applescript, bash, ...). But I prefer scripting languages.

Comment: The files and/or paths are not copied to the clipboard, only the names.  You might try using `osascript` to get the selection.

Comment: Do you need it in bash or in Applescript (curently it seems to be both)?

Comment: Please also have a look at the "Related" section at right. Similar questions have come up before, their answers should help in solving the issue.

Comment: @nohillside Is it better now? I have seen some related questions, but they are about copying to the clipboard not extracting the pathname from it.

Comment: The question is reopened now, can you please post your solution as an answer below?

Comment: @red_menace how come copying a file in finder and pasting in terminal pastes the full path?

Comment: @red_menace, RE; "The files and/or paths are not copied to the clipboard, only the names:" -- Is there are particular context your comment is applicable to? Generally speaking the quoted comment you made is not true. Using Apple's own Clipboard Viewer v 4.0 Copyright © 2004-2011 Apple Inc. I can see not only the file path of a copied file but it contents too.

Comment: Bad wording on my part.  Actually all kinds of stuff gets copied to the clipboard (file URLs, icons, images, text, etc), it is up to the individual applications to extract whatever they want.  TextEdit and Preview paste an icon, Script Editor/Debugger, BBEdit, and Finder paste the name text, Terminal pastes the path, etc.   A script can be used to coerce/extract the contents of the clipboard to the desired item, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485061/applescript-i-copied-the-finder-selection-to-the-clipboard-can-i-get-the-full

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748909/get-path-of-file-from-clipboard-in-os-x

Specifically:

First install https://github.com/programming-nu/nu:

`brew install nu`

Then this script does what we need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nush
(puts ((((((NSPasteboard generalPasteboard) pasteboardItems)
  map:    (do (pbi) (pbi stringForType: "public.file-url")))
  select: (do (url) (url)))
  map:    (do (url) ((NSURL URLWithString: url) path))) componentsJoinedByString: "\n"))
```

This helper zsh code will do a general "paste":

```
    local paste="$(pbpaste)"
    local ppaths=("${(@f)$(clipboard-to-path.nu)}")
    test -n "$ppaths[*]" && paste=($ppaths[@])
```